# How to convert tree-form tuples to matrix-form tuples?

Tags: python, python-3.x, data-structures, tuples

Pardon in advance if my question appears too naive or too basic. I'm a still learning to use SE.

Is there a quick way to convert tree-form tuple to a matrix-form tuple (triangular form)?

That is this:

```
t=((1,),(2,3,),(4,5,6,),(7,8,9,10,))
```

to this:

```
t=((1,0,0,0,),(2,3,0,0,),(4,5,6,0,),(7,8,9,10,))
```

Just an idea would suffice. I can try implementing it myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take advantage of tuple concatenating: (this is just something to start with like you said)

```
>>> (1,)+(0,)*2
(1, 0, 0)
```

and `max()` and `len()` function:

```
>>> len(max(((1,),(2,3,),(4,5,6,),(7,8,9,10,)),key = lambda x: len(x)))
4
```

Answer (score 3):

You could add 0s if the length is less than 4

```
tuple(a+(0,)*(4-len(a)) for a in t)
((1, 0, 0, 0), (2, 3, 0, 0), (4, 5, 6, 0), (7, 8, 9, 10))
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like that even if it's not optimised:

```
def tuple_to_serie(t)
    s = []
    max_len = max( [len(tup) for tup in t] )
    for tup in t :
        s.append( tup+(0,)*(max_len-len(tup)) )
    return tuple(s)
```

Then :

```
t = tuple_to_serie(t)
```